# How to show the oblique parameters S, T, and U are coefficients of d=6 operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, homework-and-exercises, electroweak, 1pi-effective-action

In Morii, Lim, Mukherjee, *The Physics of the Standard Model and Beyond.* 2004, ch. 8, they claim that the Peskin–Takeuchi oblique parameters *S, T* and *U* are in fact Wilson coefficients of certain dimension-6 operators.  On page 212, they claim that the *T* parameter is described by
$$O_T=(\phi^\dagger D_\mu \phi)\phi^\dagger D^\mu \phi)-\frac{1}{3}(\phi^\dagger D_\mu D^\mu\phi)(\phi^\dagger\phi)\,,$$
and the *S* parameter by
$$O_S=[\phi^\dagger(F_{\mu\nu}^i\sigma^i)\phi]B^{\mu\nu}\,,$$
where $\phi$ is the Higgs doublet, $F_{\mu\nu}^i$ and $\sigma^i$ are the SU(2) weak isospin field strength and sigma matrices respectively, and $B^{\mu\nu}$ is the U(1) weak hypercharge field strength.

On the next page (p. 213), problem **8.6** asks us to show that these are the operators.

How do I precisely show that these higher-dimension operators give precisely the Peskin-Takeuchi parameters?

Comment: This is all explained (and much more) [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:0807.0490). Look at eq.(89) and compare with eqs.(34) & (40).

Comment: Interested to know if you were able to work it out from there?

Comment: Thanks for the reference; I haven't looked at it carefully enough to see if I could work it out.  In any case, the paper seems to be important enough to read through.